# How to add thousands separator while user is typing?

Tags: javascript, polymer

I need to add a thousands separator while the user is typing.
I have an observer function that watches a property which is bind to the input so every time the user types in the input I get two values, newValue and oldValue.

E.g.: The user wants to type '12600' which should be displayed as '12.600'.

Until that part, my code is working.

When I went to test it, I realized that my function doesn't work properly because when I delete a single digit it won't delete it.

E.g.: '12.600' -> '1.260' wont work.

At the end of my function, I assign the new value to my property which is bind to the input value so it triggers another change and my function is executed again, which sets my property's value to the old one.

```
_turnoverObserver: function (newValue, oldValue) {
      let result = [];

      if (newValue !== undefined && newValue !== null) {
        //this.turnover = String(newValue).split('.').join('').split("").reverse().join("").match(/.{1,3}/g).join(".").split("").reverse().join("");
        //this.turnover = Number(this.turnover).toLocaleString();
        if (newValue.length > 3) {
          let withoutCommasStr = newValue.split('.').join('');
          let withoutComasArr = withoutCommasStr.split('');
          let reversedArr = withoutComasArr.reverse();
          reversedArr.forEach((num, index) => {
            if (index !== 0 && index % 3 === 0) {
              result.push('.');
            }
            result.push(num);
          });
          let finalArr = result.reverse();
          this.turnover = finalArr.join('');
        }
      }
    }
```

Say the I want to type '1260'.

1) 1

2) 12

3) 126

4) 1.620

But when I delete any number it will execute my function again but won't delete it...

1) '1.260'

2) Press delete

3) Still '1.260'

Comment: If you attach the handler to the DOM event `input` of the HTML input field and directly work with its value property, your handler works perfectly, also for the delete key (because the `input` event is not triggered if the content is changed programmatically).

Comment: @rplantiko hey thanks for your answer! Before posting the question I was thinking about that one and when you replied I just tried to attach my handler to the on-input listener but it doesn't seem to work either ... I will keep trying

Comment: Your code works with plain HTML/CSS/JavaScript. See https://jsfiddle.net/rplantiko/kbngvcyo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this jquery

```
$('input.number').keyup(function(event) {

  // skip for arrow keys
  if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

  // format number
  $(this).val(function(index, value) {
    return value
    .replace(/\D/g, "")
    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  });
});

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply! I know I can translate jQuery to JavaScript but I am sticking with vanilla. I will give your snippet a try though. Thanks again mate!

Comment: That’s going to be very annoying if someone wants to type in the middle of the number. Or possibly even just copy and paste.